# Transferring large amount of data over rest

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I'm currently working on a rest service between two servers. X application sends one object to Y but this object contains hundreds maybe thousands of child objects. X application collects required data then converts to dto and sends this dto to Y application.

For example;

```
        A
       / \
      B   B
     /     \
    C       C
   /\       /\
  D  E     D  E
```

- A object may contains hundreds of B
- Each B object may contains dozens of C
- Each C object may contains hundreds of D and dozens of E and so on

My questions are;

1. Is it reliable to transfer all these data over rest?
2. Y application uses Hibernate. Hibernate runs select queries
   before inserting data, and this causes a lot of work load. How can I
   prevent that?
3. It seems to me that putting all these data intertwined is fragile
   and not truly dependable. What can I do?

What do you think is the best way to do this whole process I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Using REST is an okay hack, HTTP is a streaming protocol; the main issues are 1) what happens when the connection dies part way through sending  and 2) loading all the stuff into memory. If you were to use Hibernate properly - using a query cursor you could avoid 2) by streaming the query results. Fixing 1) requires getting rid of REST. If you threw all this away, Hibernate, REST etc and used a modern, reactive, communications protocol then both issues would solve themselves.

Comment: What is the alternative? According to reliability REST is not better or worse than RMI. If you need to transfer such amounts of data, I would question the reason for that.
Problem with OR-Mapping that, for Updates you first need the object in hand. Therefore selects. But these can be done by Hibernate quite fast using nifty Joins (if you use eager loading). The greater problem is the amount of objects created in main-memory and comparing those with the structure you copied from the other server ... sounds very much like to much redundancy of logic and data in your system

Answer (score 1):

As far as huge data over REST is concerned, I provide below the following approaches.

1. As suggested by Boris Sir, you can adopt Reactive Stream concept in Rest.
2. If the data is bit huge, it is not recommended to send all the data over rest in the form Json or Xml. You can put a limit condition as a parameter so that data will be sent as per the limit. Think about a situation, you are making a query to github about all the existing repositories and each repository may have several files, in this case you can use limit as request parameter.
3. If you think, the data to be sent over Rest is large or moderately large but not overly very large, you can use gzip compression(**Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate**, **Content-Encoding: gzip**) while sending the data over Rest.

Besides I see that you have hierarchical model of data, it will be good to have categorization and an individual Rest end point for each category with limit. To make it more specific, if A is a kind of category, get required data with A category type with certain limit, similarly for others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The A object is a complex product. I need every detail of A. This data transfer happens one time for each product. If product needs an update or delete or new addition each of A,B,C,D,E, object has it's own rest service, these operations can be done over their own rest services.
The main problem here is sending object A and all it's child objects for the first time. I have to make sure all of the data is succesfully sent and saved into target.

Comment: Yes @mnesimi, I understand your problem, you think like this the product type is mobile phone and each mobile phone has n types of phone like LG, Samsung, Apple etc and again each phone company has m number of models. So in this case use a categorization and use limit to provide to the user. It is not recommended to provide all, think like pagination type concept.